# Lyx error while importing LaTeX file

Tags: lyx

I am trying to import a LaTeX file to LyX, but I am getting this error:

```
An error occurred while running:
"/Volumes/LyX-2.1.3/LyX.app/Contents/MacOS/tex2lyx" -f "root.tex" "root.lyx"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To help you would need to post a minimal example (http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample) of your root.tex file. Also, let us know if you're able to import other .tex files (e.g. simple ones).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fjvsk8eh482i30/root.tex?dl=0

Comment: This is my root.tex file

Comment: @user73831 please see my question above. and please comment with `@` and then my username so I am notified that you are responding to me (otherwise I might not remember to check back at this question)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that LyX does not have a layout file (a file that is specific to LyX, not LaTeX) for the class "ifacconf"

More information is given if you run LyX from the command line:

```
Cannot read layout file `'.
Error reading `'
(Check `ifacconf')
Check your installation and try Options/Reconfigure...
Error: Could not read layout file for textclass "ifacconf".
support/Systemcall.cpp (288): Systemcall: 'tex2lyx -f "root.tex" "root.lyx"' finished with exit code 1
Error: Cannot convert file
----------------------------------------
An error occurred while running:
tex2lyx -f "root.tex" "root.lyx"
```

You would thus need to create a layout file. To get started on this, read the section "5 Installing New Document Classes, Layouts, and Templates" in Help > Customization. There are some less technical guides out there if you want to Google "creating a LyX layout file" or something similar.